I am trying to analyze accelerometer data using the GGIR package but getting timestamp error attached below
I'm trying to use the GGIR package in R to analyze raw actigraphy data. The excel tables with the raw data contain 4 columns (HEADER_TIMESTAMP, X, Y, Z). HEADER_TIMESTAMP is in the format "2000-01-08T12:30:00Z".However, when I run my code, there is an error message that "character string is not in a standard unambiguous format."
Example data:
HEADER_TIMESTAMP    X            Y            Z
1/8/2000 12:30           0.534   0.106   -0.877
1/8/2000 12:30           0.487   0.126   -0.874
1/8/2000 12:30           0.519   0.085   -0.874
1/8/2000 12:30           0.543   0.114   -0.871
This is my code:

library(GGIR)
library(bitops)
library(covr)
library(testthat)
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)
library(data.table)
library(Rcpp)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(signal)
library(zoo)
library(matlab)
library(GENEAread)
library(tuneR)
library(unisensR)
library(ineq)
library(stats)
library(utils)    

actigraphy_data <- data.frame(
  HEADER_TIMESTAMP = c("2000-01-08T12:30:00Z", "2000-01-08T12:30:00Z", 
                       "2000-01-08T12:30:00Z", "2000-01-08T12:30:00Z"),
  X = c(0.534, 0.487, 0.519, 0.543),
  Y = c(0.106, 0.126, 0.085, 0.114),
  Z = c(-0.877, -0.874, -0.874, -0.871)
)

write.csv(actigraphy_data, "C:/path_to_your_directory/actigraphy_data.csv", row.names = FALSE)

data_dir <- "C:/path_to_your_directory/"

g.shell.GGIR(mode=c(1,2,3,4,5),
             datadir=data_dir ,
             outputdir="C:/Users/...",
             studyname="TEST",
             minimumFileSizeMB = 0.01,
             f0=1, #number of files - will need to change
             f1=0,
             # Time format to fix the issue:
             #rmc.format.time = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p",  
             #desiredtz = "America/New_York",
             #rmc.nrow = Inf,
             #rmc.skip =0,
             #rmc.firstrow.acc = 2,
             #desiredtz = "America/New_York",
             #rmc.unit.acc = "g",
             #rmc.unit.time = 'POSIX',
             #rmc.format.time = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S",
             #rmc.col.time = 1,
             #rmc.sf = 80,
             overwrite = FALSE,
             do.imp=TRUE,
             idloc=2,
             print.filename=TRUE,
             storefolderstructure = TRUE,
             #-------------------------------
             # Part 1 parameters:
             #-------------------------------
             windowsizes = c(5,900,3600),
             do.cal=TRUE,
             do.enmo = TRUE,
             do.anglez=TRUE,
             do.mod = FALSE,
             do.hfen = FALSE,
             do.en = FALSE,
             chunksize=1,
             printsummary=TRUE,
             #-------------------------------
             # Part 2 parameters:
             #-------------------------------               
             strategy = 2,
             ndayswindow=7,
             hrs.del.start = 0,
             hrs.del.end = 0,
             maxdur = 7,
             includedaycrit = 16,
             L5M5window = c(0,24),
             M5L5res = 10,
             winhr = c(5,10),
             qlevels = c(c(1380/1440),c(1410/1440)),
             qwindow=c(0,24),
             ilevels = c(seq(0,400,by=50),8000),
             excludefirstlast = TRUE,
             #includenightcrit = 16,
             mvpathreshold =c(100,120),
             #-------------------------------
             # Part 3 parameters:
             #-------------------------------
             timethreshold= 5,
             anglethreshold=5,
             ignorenonwear = TRUE,
             #-------------------------------
             # Part 4 parameters:
             #-------------------------------
             #excludefirstlast = TRUE,
             includenightcrit = 16,
             def.noc.sleep = c(1),
             outliers.only = FALSE,
             #criterror = 4,
             relyonsleeplog = FALSE,
             #sleeplogidnum = TRUE,
             colid=1,
             coln1=2,
             do.visual = TRUE,
             nnights = 9,
             #-------------------------------
             # Part 5 parameters:
             #-------------------------------
             # Key functions: Merging physical activity with sleep analyses
             iglevels = TRUE,
             threshold.lig = c(30,40,50),
             threshold.mod = c(100,120),
             threshold.vig = c(400,500),
             boutcriter = 0.8,
             boutcriter.in = 0.9,
             boutcriter.lig = 0.8,
             boutcriter.mvpa = 0.8,
             boutdur.in = c(10,20,30),
             boutdur.lig = c(1,5,10),
             boutdur.mvpa = c(1,5,10),
             timewindow = c("WW"),
             #-----------------------------------
             # Report generation
             #-------------------------------
             do.report=c(2,4,5), #want sleep report only
             visualreport = FALSE,
             dofirstpage = TRUE,
             epochvalues2csv=TRUE,
             viewingwindow=1)
#end

This is the error that I get when running the code:

"Errors and warnings for GT3XPLUS-AccelerationCalibrated-1x8x0.NEO1G62402505.2000-01-16-12-00-00-000-P0000.sensor.csv.gz$message [1] "character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"
$call as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...)"

How can I either change the Header Timestamp format or change the GGIR code to match this format?

See https://github.com/wadpac/GGIR/issues/1237 for a discussion of that data (likely the NHANES raw data).
